# Rotate PolyhedronData

Tags: graphics3d, polyhedra

I'd like to create a `Graphics3D` rendering of a rotated Polyhedron taken from `PolyhedronData[]`

```
myGraphic = PolyhedronData[
 "Icosahedron", "Graphics3D"]
```

I have tried
    `Graphics3D@GeometricTransformation[myGraphic,
     RotationTransform[Pi/6, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}]]`

and numerous variations thereon... all without success.

I suspect my problem is a failure to get a Graphics3D object from PolyhedronData[], but cannot be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Graphics3D@Rotate[myGraphic[[1]], Pi/6, {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}]
```

Notice that you want `Rotate` to act on the graphics *primitive* (a `GraphicsComplex` in this case), not on the whole `Graphics3D` object.

Comment: Oh... so simple (+1).  (How did you know that it was the first component of the PolyhedronData?) . [Acceptance in 10 minutes...]

Comment: I knew that from experience =) But one can always apply `InputForm` to `Graphics3D` objects...